# 時系列データで、時間の歯抜けと欠損のあるデータを処理したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas

時系列で、１時間ごとに以下のような形式でデータの入っているものがあります。

```
datetime               on_off
2020-05-31 11:31                                      　　　　　　　　　  00000000000000000000000000000
2020-05-31 12:00       000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-01 13:00       111111000100000111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-03 14:18                         　　　　　  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-05 15:00       000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-06 03:00       000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

前提条件として、

・欠損している箇所には空白もNaNも入っておらず、値として入ってるのは数字が始まる部分から
・「on／off」データは一行に60個あるのが正常なもの
・datetimeで「11:31」のように途中から始まってる場合は[on/off]列は31分から始まるので29個値が並ぶ

出したい形としては、

```
2020-04-13 11:31:00    0
2020-04-13 11:32:00    0
2020-04-13 11:33:00    0
2020-04-13 11:34:00    0
[省略]
2020-04-13 11:59:00    0
```

のように毎分１レコードのように対応させたいのです。

```
start_at, end_at = df.datetime.min(), df.datetime.max()
res = df.reindex(pd.date_range(start_at, end_at, freq="T"))
```

で、まず分毎のデータを作成し、

```
df["on_off"].str.split('')
list_split =[[a for a in y if a != '']for y in y]
```

でリスト化して結合することで対応しようとしたのですが、日にち自体も歯抜けしている為に二つの数が合わず、
結合ができませんでした。

このようなデータに対してアプローチ自体が間違えてるのでしょうか・・・。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Comment: datetimeの値は、必ず秒は0なのですか？

Comment: ちなみに提示されているデータはファイル内容そのままですか？ 一部全角空白が入っているようですが転記ミス？ それからいったんpandasに読み込んでいるのか読み込もうとしているのか、その辺の処理はどうしようとしているのでしょう？

Comment: こちら [時系列データで、時間の歯抜けと欠損のあるデータ](https://teratail.com/questions/281402) でも回答が2件付いてますね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

例えばデータを以下のように`CSV`にしたとすると：

```
datetime,on_off
2020-05-31 11:31,                               00000000000000000000000000000
2020-05-31 12:00,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-01 13:00,111111000100000111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-03 14:18,                  000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-05 15:00,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
2020-06-06 03:00,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

以下のようなプログラムでリスト化出来るでしょう。
(元データの形式(CSV/TXTファイルまたはPandas.DataFrame等)が違えば、それに応じて色々変わりますが)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import csv
from pprint import pprint

with open('status.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    csvdata = [row for row in reader]

csvdata.pop(0)  ## 項目名行削除

minuteonofflist = []
for tm, sts in csvdata:
    onoffs = list(sts.strip())
    datalen = len(onoffs)
    basetime = datetime.strptime(tm, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    timelist = [(basetime + timedelta(minutes=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in range(datalen)]
    minuteonofflist.extend([[t,f] for t,f in zip(timelist, onoffs)])

pprint(minuteonofflist)
```

結果は以下に。

```
[['2020-05-31 11:31:00', '0'],
 ['2020-05-31 11:32:00', '0'],
 ['2020-05-31 11:33:00', '0'],
 ['2020-05-31 11:34:00', '0'],
 ['2020-05-31 11:35:00', '0'],
～省略～
 ['2020-06-06 03:55:00', '0'],
 ['2020-06-06 03:56:00', '0'],
 ['2020-06-06 03:57:00', '0'],
 ['2020-06-06 03:58:00', '0'],
 ['2020-06-06 03:59:00', '0']]
```

---

質問ではデータの有る部分については要望が出ていますが、データの無い部分についてはどうするか書かれていませんね。
以下のような選択肢が考えられます。

- データの無い部分のレコードは不要
- データの無い部分でもレコードを作成する
  on/off状態のデータは以下のいずれか

  - 空文字列
  - 空白1文字
  - on/offどちらか固定
  - 最後のデータの状態を引き継ぐ
  - 最後のデータと次の最初のデータの間で変化等を補完する

Comment: データが有る場合、の質問でした。色々と情報が足りず申し訳ありません。編集頂いた通り、右詰めのデータとなります。ご回答頂きありがとうございました、無事解決致しました・・・！